# Реализация ввода пароля

Tags: javascript, css

столкнулся с проблемой , хотел сделать 6 раздельных инпутов, в которые можно будет вводить цифры, чтобы при вводе цифры, меня сразу перебрасывало на следующий инпут, я сделал, но работает оно очень косячно, я ввел одну цифру , чтобы перейти на другой блок мне надо нажать на него, хотел бы сделать так, чтобы при вводе цифры в блок, меня сразу перебрасывало на следующий ?

```css
                                                                                 .inputs {
        display: flex;
        width: 50px;
        background: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.2);
        height: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        align-items: center;
}

.main__inputs {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
}
```

```html
    <div class="main__inputs">
             <input class="inputs">
             <input class="inputs">
             <input class="inputs">
             <input class="inputs">
             <input class="inputs">
             <input class="inputs">
   </div>
```

Comment: О живой автор такого креатива. Но зачем?! Что бы мне было неудобно в него пароль копипастить?

Comment: @AlexeyTen , Ну это не для пароля, а скорее для пин-кода, я думаю. В мобильных приложениях видел так часто делают.

Comment: Ну тебе придётся написать кучу JS, обрабатывать клики в эти поля, обрабатывать удаление из полей. В общем куча проблем на ровном месте и без видимого профита.

Comment: Или найти готовое решение, я уверен таких штук десяток есть

Comment: я не знаю как правильно загуглить эту штуку

Comment: https://snipp.ru/jquery/input-pincode нашел вот такую реализацию

Comment: Не сильно нравится джейквери, а найти что-то подобное на vue или просто js не могу (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант в виде отдельного компонента с теневым деревом. Не идеально, код еще можно дополнить/улучшить.

Использовал свойства элементов `Element.previousElementSibling` и `Element.nextElementSibling`, чтобы менять фокус на следующий/предыдущий инпут.

```js
class HTMLSplittedInput extends HTMLElement {  
  
  #hostAttributes = ['items', 'type'];
  #items = 6;
  #type = 'text';
  #shadow;
  
  set items(value) {
    if (isNaN(+value)) return;
    this.#items = +value; 
  }
  set type(value) {
    this.#type = value; 
  }
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.#shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'closed'}); // присоединяем закрытое теневое дерево, к элементам нет доступа из document
    this.#initAttributes();
    this.#fill();
    this.#setStyles();
    this.#handleInputs();
  }
  
  /**
  * Добавляем стили в теневое дерево для инпутов
  */
  #setStyles() {
    let style = document.createElement('style');
        style.textContent = `input {
            display: flex;
            width: 50px;
            background: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.2);
            height: 20px;
            border-radius: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }`;
    this.#shadow.prepend(style);
  }
  
  /**
  * Заполняем элемент инпутами, кол-во зависит от аттрибута items
  */
  #fill() {
    for (let i = 0; i < this.#items; i++) {
      const input = document.createElement('input');
            input.type = this.#type;
      this.#shadow.append(input);
    }
  }
  
  /**
  * собираем значения с аттрибутов
  */
  #initAttributes() {
     for(const attr of this.attributes) {
      if (this.#hostAttributes.includes(attr.name)) {
        this[attr.name] = attr.value;
        continue;
      }
    }
  }
  
  /**
  * Обрабатываем нажатия с клавиатуры
  */
  #handleInputs() {       
    this.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      event.preventDefault(); // иначе получим двойной ввод

      const current = this.#shadow.activeElement; // текущий элемент в фокусе

      if (current instanceof HTMLInputElement == false) return; // проверка на то, что в фокусе инпут
      if (event.key == 'Backspace') { // если нажат backspace удаляем значение из поля 
        current.value = '';
        if (current.previousElementSibling) current.previousElementSibling.focus(); // идем к предыдущему
        return;
      }
      if (isNaN(+event.key)) { // проверка на число
        current.value = current.value;
        return;
      }
      if (!current.nextElementSibling) { // если больше инпутов не осталось
        current.value = event.key;
        return void this.#end();
      }
      current.value = event.key; // записываем в поле значение
      current.nextElementSibling.focus(); // идем к следующему
    });
  }
  
  /**
  * Проверяет все значения инпутов, записывает в массив и отправляет в виде эвента end
  */
  #end() {
    let current = this.#shadow.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling; // первым идет <style>
    const values = [current.value];
    while (values.length < this.#shadow.children.length - 1) {
      current = current.nextElementSibling;
      values.push(current.value);
    }
    this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('end', { detail: values }));
  }
}

// определяем пользовательский элемент split-input
customElements.define('splitted-input', HTMLSplittedInput);

const splitted = document.querySelector('splitted-input');
      splitted.addEventListener('end', (event) => { // добавляем слушатель эвента end
        console.log(event.detail);
      });
```

```css
splitted-input {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<splitted-input items="6" type="text"></splitted-input>
```